# Why does \addcontentsline not add to TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Rechtevergabe Testdokument}
\author{Test1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bereich A}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Kapitel I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Kapitel II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bereich B}
\end{document}
```

Gives me no TOC at all (after running *pdflatex* twice). Moving `\addcontentsline` to before `\tableofcontents` and removing `\newpage` did no change. I intend to obtain a document with TOC only. Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

The `\addcontentsline` commands are written at `\shipout`. But your page is empty. Removing the `\newpage` after `\tableofcontents` should work (it does for me) or put something on the page with the `\addcontentsline` commands, e.g. `\newpage\mbox{}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a document consisting of only a toc, this snippet (copied from [Jevon](http://jevon.org/wiki/addcontentsline_Doesn%27t_Work_in_LaTeX)) will help:

```
\newcommand\immediateaddcontentsline[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\origwrite\write
  \def\write{\immediate\origwrite}%
  \addcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  \endgroup
}
```